# Using Enums as arguments in vba

Tags: ms-access, enums, vba

I'm using Access 2000 and am trying to call a VBA function procedure using the RunCode action.
How can I use an Enum as an argument for that function call?

(I've simplified the code in the following example, so we can focus on the important parts)

The Enum is in a module named *Configuration_Enum*:

```
Public Enum configuration
  val1 = 1
  val2 = 2
End Enum
```

The function using that enum is in the module *Configuration_Module*:

```
Public Function getConfiguration(config As configuration) As Int
  getConfiguration = config
End Funtion
```

I can call the function using the Enum as an argument without problems via VBA:

```
getConfiguration( Configuration_Enum.val1 )
```

Now I want to make that function-call using vba (using the RunCode action), but it's not working:

```
getConfiguration( [Modules]![Configuration_Enum].[val1] )
```

Unfortunately I'm using a German Version of Access and there is no Error-Id, so I can only give you my translation of the error message:

> The Object doesn't contain the automation object 'val1'.
>
> You've tried to run a Visual-Basic Procedure to set an Object-Property.
>   However automatization-processes have no access to that property.

Is the thing I'm trying to accomplish even possible or am I just doint it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't. Your options are:

Good: get rid of the macro and do it in VBA.

Meh: use the value from the enum as parameter, i.e. `getConfiguration(1)`

Comment: True. Neither can you use the Enum in expressions in SQL of a query. Best advice is to skip the macros. There even is a wizard for converting them to VBA.